# DelegatingFilterProxy / springSecurityFilterChain -- should the protected path be /* or /**?

Tags: spring, spring-security

It seems like it *should* be "/**", but the example in the Spring security reference uses "/*".

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>

</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <!-- protected URL path -->
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Why does it seems like it should be `/**`? It's an ant path matcher and not a url pattern specified in the servlet api. Use `/*`.

Comment: See this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html).